# How can I get unique keys mapping an array of arrays?

Tags: reactjs

My prop is `arrays: [[], [], []]` with each inner array containing objects with different values. I'm mapping over the array, then passing the inner arrays to another component like so (really dumbed down example),

`{arrays.map(values => <div key={???}><InnerComponent values={values} /></div>)}`

I'm getting the warning about a unique key, but I can't think of a great way to derive a key other than `stringify`, which seems really heavy-handed. The user can add/remove items, so index isn't a good solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of passing down an array of arrays, pass down an object of objects instead, generating random unique keys for the objects, and use that for the key. Something like

```
// https://stackoverflow.com/q/105034
function uuidv4() {
  return 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-4xxx-yxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx'.replace(/[xy]/g, function(c) {
    var r = Math.random() * 16 | 0, v = c == 'x' ? r : (r & 0x3 | 0x8);
    return v.toString(16);
  });
}
```

and instead of

```
[
  [
    value1,
    value2,
    value3
    // ...
```

make

```
{
  <randomUUID>: {
    <randomUUID>: value1,
    <randomUUID>: value2,
    <randomUUID>: value3
    // ...
```

where a UUID is generated only when a new item is generated, or on mount - once an item is paired with a UUID, it should stay paired until the item is deleted.

Answer (score -3):

Just add index
value => ... key={???}
(value, index) => key={index}

Comment: The question says *The user can add/remove items, so index isn't a good solution.*